# Question about proof of Ore's Theorem

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

**Ore's Theorem:** If $G$ is a simple graph such that for every pair of non-adjacent vertices $u, v$ of $G$ we have $d(u) + d(v) ≥ |G|$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

I am able to follow the [classic proof given at ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ore's_Theorem) quite easily with the exception of one line:

> For a given $n≥3$, let $G$ be the graph with the most possible edges such that G is non-Hamiltonian which satisfies (1).

How come this doesn't effectively add another condition to the theorem, proving:

> If $G$ is a simple graph such that for every pair of non-adjacent
>   vertices $u, v$ of $G$ we have $d(u) + d(v) ≥ |G|$ **and *G* is *non-Hamiltonian maximal***, then $G$ is
>   Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is by a form of induction, namely maximal counterexample.  Let $S$ denote the set of all graphs on $n$ vertices, that violate the theorem.  If $S$ is empty, we are happy as the theorem is true.  If $S$ is nonempty, it must be finite, as there are only finitely many graphs on $n$ vertices.  Hence, if we consider the ordering on $S$ based on number of edges, we can find a maximal example in $S$.   (rest of theorem) Contradiction!  Hence $S$ cannot be nonempty.

Comment: Ah, of course! Because we can only reduce the degrees in "less than maximal" graphs, so they would clearly also violate Ore's condition.

Comment: @vadim123 I have a question—what if the hypothesis for Ore's Lemma was deg(u) + deg(v) $\geq$ $n-1$?